# Multiple select how to capture all selections in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using a multiple options select in my HTML form, when I select more than one option and use the 'GET' method in my form I see this

**url?Ripples=1.3&Ripples=1.4**

As you can see each selection has the same name, when I pass this to my jsp and display the variable I only get this first option which in this case is 1.3. How do I get all the selections into my java strings?

Comment: @matty1 - please click the checkmark underneath the answer to mark it as answered

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
String[] ripples = request.getParameterValues("Ripples");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getParameterValues("Ripples")
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.getParameterValues(argument)` will return a list of the selected items.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should be handled by a **POST** request.